# Firefox Addon: WebExtension or Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have read a lot of articles regarding WebExtensions and Add-on SDK.

It's noted that WebExtension API advatanges includes compatibility across various browsers.

However, my questions are:

- Is Add-on SDK platform dependent (Firefox)?
- Will Add-on SDK continue to be supported in the future?

Comment: This question is not acceptable on Stack Overflow, because it's considered to be "opinion-based". Please take a look at the site [tour], the ["Don't ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) guides to get a better idea what can be asked here.

Comment: Hello, sorry for not 'understanding' the rules of asking question, i have updated the question :)

Comment: No problem! It takes time with SO to learn those rules. Now it's an answerable question. I cleaned it up and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is Add-on SDK platform dependent (Firefox)?**

Yes. Note that it's also supported on Firefox for Android, which is currently one of the very few ways to get an extension running on mobile.

**Will Add-on SDK continue to be supported in the future?**

<del>We can only speculate how long the support would be.</del> Active development of the Add-on SDK stopped, and Mozilla is focusing on developing WebExtension API.

Quote from [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons#Developing_add-ons):

> There are currently several toolsets for developing Firefox add-ons, but WebExtensions will become the standard by the end of 2017. **The rest are expected to be deprecated over the same period of time.**

So according to this quote, Add-on SDK is being deprecated in a timeframe of a year.

Note that both extension models offer different features: WebExtensions are unlikely to ever cover all functionality of Add-on SDK.

Finally..

**WebExtension API advatanges includes compatibility across various browsers.**

Not strictly true, since extension models are only *partially* compatible between Chrome, Firefox and Edge. At least fow now, you'll need platform-specific workarounds and some features are either not yet implemented or not going to be implemented in all platforms. Still, it's possible to have a unified codebase.

Comment: Hello again!! 
errrr, sorry for asking another question,

i wanted to ask whether webextension supports the features i'm looking for, my add on required the features:

- read through the HTML code of a social media
- getting the privacy settings of each element of the social media
- invoke each of the HTML element with CSS code (colour the element with different colour based on their privacy settings)

*Errrr, i'm not sure whether to ask it here,or repost another question in stackoverflow

Comment: Of course, this should be another question.